# Laravel getting data from database giving me array of value

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php 

$apiMonitor = DB::table('sites')->select('uptime_access_code')->get();

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.uptimerobot.com/v2/getMonitors",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "api_key=Private&format=json&logs=1&monitors=$apiMonitor&custom_uptime_ratios=1-7-30",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
$data = json_decode($response);
$custom_uptime = ($data->monitors[0]->custom_uptime_ratio);
$uptime = explode("-",$custom_uptime);
}

?>
```

I already get my value of my uptime access but its an array The thing is my monitor need only the value but when i dd() it this what happens.

**This is my dd($apiMonitor);**

[image: apiMonitor]

The output I want to happen is

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "api_key=Private&format=json&logs=1&monitors=778780885&custom_uptime_ratios=1-7-30",`

The output that you can see is working already but how can I able to get the data from the database and put the value of uptime_access_code to my monitor? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` returns a collection of all of the rows, since you're getting just one column and not specifying a where clause. If you only want one value, you can use `value` to get a single value (previous versions used `pluck`)

```
$apiMonitor = DB::table('sites')->value('uptime_access_code');
```